# Office365 REST API - Creating a calendar event with attachments

Tags: office365, microsoft-graph-api, office365api, outlook-restapi

I am unable to create a calendar event with attachments using Office365's Rest API. Creating events without attachments is not a problem. Trying to create events with attachments creates the event, but the files I send are not added. The server responds with a 201 response code.

I am sending a POST request to:

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/calendars/$(calendarID)/events
```

I use the following Authorization header:

```
Authorization: Bearer $(tokenString)
```

Request payload:

```
{
  "start": {
    "dateTime": "2017-09-27T20:00:00.000",
    "timeZone": "UTC"
  },
  "end": {
    "dateTime": "2017-09-27T21:00:00.000",
    "timeZone": "UTC"
  },
  "attendees": [
    {
      "emailAddress": {
        "address": "person@example.com"
      },
      "type": "Required"
    }
  ],
  "subject": "Example subject",
  "body": {
    "content": "Example content",
    "contentType": "Text"
  },
  "hasAttachments": true,
  "sensitivity": "Normal",
  "attachments": [
    {
      "@odata.type": "#microsoft.graph.fileAttachment",
      "name": "$(fileName)",
      "contentBytes": "$(base64EncodedString)"
    }
  ]
}
```

I'm following the documentation at https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/beta/api/calendar_post_events. My event follows the [event schema](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/beta/resources/event), and the attachments follow the [fileAttachment schema](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/beta/resources/fileattachment).

I have tried different values for @odata.type, removing hasAttachments from the request, as well as adding name, size, and contentType fields to the attachment. All of these give the same result - a 201 response, and an event created without attachments.

Any help would be much appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I see this too! I'm able to post an attachment to the event after it's created, just not include one with the initial create payload.

So as a workaround, you can create the event, then do

```
POST /me/events/{eventid}/attachments

{
  "@odata.type": "#microsoft.graph.fileAttachment",
  "name": "$(fileName)",
  "contentBytes": "$(base64EncodedString)"
}
```

I'll check with the calendaring folks on this to see why it's not working during the initial POST.

Comment: This workaround works, thanks! Ideally I'd like to avoid the extra requests and POST all the data at once, but this works well for now.