# Why are calendar events created via the graph API sometimes missing attendees?

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-calendar

My application uses delegated user access tokens to interact with the graph API. These access tokens have `Calendars.ReadWrite.Shared` permission.

When creating a calendar event on behalf of the logged-in user, the application creates the event, adds attachments, and adds attendees as separate requests, in that order. The rationale for doing so comes from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50714919/office365-rest-api-calendar-event-attachments-not-visible-for-recipients) question -- The attendees have to be added after the attachments, or else the attendees won't see the attachments.

The process looks like this:

1. Create Event: POST - `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/calendars/{calendar_id}/events`

   Request Body:

   ```
   {
       "start": <start_time>,
       "end": <end_time>,
       "subject": <summary>,
       "body": {"content": <description>, "contentType": "HTML"},
       "sensitivity": <"Private" | "Normal">
   }
   ```
2. Add Attachments: POST - `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/calendars/{calendar_id}/events/{event_id}/attachments` (once for each attachment, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46438302/office365-rest-api-creating-a-calendar-event-with-attachments))
3. Add Attendees by updating the event: PATCH -         `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/calendars/{calendar_id}/events/{event_id}`

   Request Body:

   ```
   {"attendees": <attendees>, "locations": <locations>}
   ```

In some (but not all) cases the attendees added in step 3 don't show up on the calendar event, even though they are present in the response body from the PATCH request to add the attendees. For example, the response to the PATCH request in step 3 is a 200 status code with the following response body (most keys omitted):

```
{
    . . .
    'attendees': [
        {
            'type': 'required',
            'emailAddress': {'address': <attendee_1_email>, 'name': <attendee_1_name>},
            'status': {'time': '0001-01-01T00:00:00Z', 'response': 'none'}},
        {
            'type': 'required',
            'emailAddress': {'address': <attendee_2_email>, 'name': <attendee_2_name>},
            'status': {'time': '0001-01-01T00:00:00Z', 'response': 'none'}
        }
    ],
    'iCalUId': '040000008200E00074C5B7101A82E00800000000F479DE9EE035D601000000000000000010000000FBDBFAB438A5E840909F45F20F158E21',
    'id': 'AAMkADcyMzRlMmVjLWFiYmUtNDVmMy04NTg0LWQzYjNmN2U5OWRjMABGAAAAAAAc9_qSTiomRKxjr7R_hq5GBwC0CN1kXdTSSrZO4_ImB_wpAAACr6PWAAC0CN1kXdTSSrZO4_ImB_wpAAEQJo-HAAA='
    . . .
}
```

But when fetching the event immediately after receiving the above response from the PATCH request, via GET -         `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/calendars/{calendar_id}/events/{event_id}`, the response body describing the event has an empty array for the attendees, and the user doesn't see any attendees on the event in the O365 web UI.

```
{
    . . .
    'attendees': [],
    'iCalUId': '040000008200E00074C5B7101A82E00800000000F479DE9EE035D601000000000000000010000000FBDBFAB438A5E840909F45F20F158E21',
    'id': 'AAMkADcyMzRlMmVjLWFiYmUtNDVmMy04NTg0LWQzYjNmN2U5OWRjMABGAAAAAAAc9_qSTiomRKxjr7R_hq5GBwC0CN1kXdTSSrZO4_ImB_wpAAACr6PWAAC0CN1kXdTSSrZO4_ImB_wpAAEQJo-HAAA='
    . . .
}
```

Comment: Hi! Have you managed to find an answer for this issue? For me it still happens randomly...

Comment: Hi! No, unfortunately we never were able to get to the bottom of this. It only happens for a small subset of our clients on Microsoft365. Unfortunately the best work-around we could come up with was to ask them not to use attachments :(